# I am losing user information (session) on refreshing and between tabs while using iron-session and next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am currently working on a project using iron-session and next.js. I don't lose my user on clicking **Link** tags. But if I refresh user becomes undefined. Cookie is set and doesn't get deleted on refresh. I don't know what is wrong.

Here is my login.ts code:

```
export default withIronSessionApiRoute(loginRoute, sessionOptions);

async function loginRoute(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {

    try {
        const {
            data: {tcId, admin, userName},
        } = await axios('http://localhost:8080/user/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: JSON.stringify(req.body),
        });
        const user = {tcId: tcId, userName: userName, admin: admin} as User;
        req.session.user = user;
        await req.session.save();
        
        res.json(user);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message: (error as Error).message})
    }}
```

Here is my session.ts code:

```
// this file is a wrapper with defaults to be used in both API routes and `getServerSideProps` functions
import type { IronSessionOptions } from 'iron-session'
import type { User } from '../pages/api/user'

export const sessionOptions: IronSessionOptions = {
  password: process.env.SECRET_COOKIE_PASSWORD as string,
  cookieName: 'eys-cookie',
  // secure: true should be used in production (HTTPS) but can't be used in development (HTTP)
  cookieOptions: {
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  },
};

// This is where we specify the typings of req.session.*
declare module 'iron-session' {
  interface IronSessionData {
    user?: User
  }
}
```

As I said previously. I don't lose my user. While routing around using **Link** tags from next.
Refreshing causes to lose my user. Also other tabs don't reach my user.

I can show more code if wanted. But I think problem is here.

Comment: How are you checking if user is authenticated or not?

Comment: was there ever a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and solved the tab switching by setting:

```
revalidateOnFocus = false,
```

for the useSWR function

sample

```
const fetcher = (url: any) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
  const options = {
    revalidateOnFocus: false,
  };
  const {
    data: session,
    error,
    mutate: mutateUser,
  } = useSWR<Session>("/api/session", fetcher, options);
```

you can also explore other options here https://swr.vercel.app/docs/options

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still losing session on refreshing page... Please if anyone has a solution

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to add `SWRconfig` on the index or app component:

```
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { SWRConfig } from 'swr'
import fetchJson from 'lib/fetchJson'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <SWRConfig
         value={{
        fetcher: fetchJson,
        onError: (err) => {
          console.error(err)
        },
      }}
    >
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SWRConfig>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```